# Return only values contained in list C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a `List<int> ListOfIDs` containing some numbers which are IDs.

I have a `List<CustomClass> ListOfObjects` containing some objects, which properties reflecting their IDs.

I've searched high and low for a Linq query that will allow me to return from my List a sublist of only those objects which have an ID that is contained within the List.

My attempt does not compile and I cannot seem to correct the syntax :

```
List<CustomClass> SubList = ListOfObjects.Where(ListOfIDs.Contains(p => p.ID))
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to do like this?

```
List<CustomClass> SubList = ListOfObjects
        .Where(obj => ListOfIDs.Contains(obj.ID))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: This works in most ORM Linq providers (in fact it's the go-to way to specify an "in" clause), and was going to be my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need:

```
List<CustomClass> SubList = ListOfObjects.Where(p => ListOfIDs.Contains(p.ID)).ToList();
```

Don't forget to call `ToList()` in the end.

Also consider using `HashSet` for `ListOfIDs`, because complexity of `Contains` operation is just `O(1)`. But, well it depends on how much data you have.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correct syntax for what you're trying to do:

```
... ListOfObjects.Where(p => ListOfIDs.Contains(p.ID)).ToList();
```

Though this might be faster that the `Where(Contains)` method:

```
var sublist = (
    from obj in ListOfObjects
    join id in ListOfIDs on id equals obj.ID
    select obj ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this piece of code snippet:

```
List<CustomClass> SubList = ListOfObjects.Where(o => ListOfIDs.Contains(o.ID))
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Nothing its just that i usually use it this way. Won't it serve the purpose?

Comment: It's entirely redundant.  Other than taking a tiny bit of time to run and wasting a bit of space on the screen, it won't do a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I have edited the code. Is it better now?